# map over multiple arrays and only return specific ones

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, charts

I currently have an axios get request that fetches data from a nasa API and returns it into a list of arrays.

```
getDataHandler= () => {
  axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?api_key=DEMO_KEY',)
  .then((response) => {
    const restructuredData = response.data.near_earth_objects.map(
      ({ name, estimated_diameter, close_approach_data }) => {
        const close_approaches = close_approach_data && close_approach_data.length
          ? close_approach_data.map(({ orbiting_body }) => orbiting_body)
          : ["no orbited planet"] // If the array doesn't exist, just use an empty array.

        return [
          name,
          estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_min,
          estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_max,
          close_approaches[0]
        ]
      })
    })
```

It returns a list of arrays that look like this:

```
0: (4) ["21277 (1996 TO5)", 1.6016033798, 3.5812940302, "Mars"]
1: (4) ["162038 (1996 DH)", 1.2721987854, 2.844722965, "no orbited planet"]
2: (4) ["189058 (2000 UT16)", 1.332155667, 2.978790628, "Earth"]
3: (4) ["276274 (2002 SS41)", 0.9650614696, 2.1579430484, "Earth"]
4: (4) ["322913 (2002 CM1)", 1.214940408, 2.7166893409, "Jupiter"]
5: (4) ["435730 (2008 UK90)", 0.4411182, 0.9863702813, "no orbited planet"]
```

Then it gets the list and `setState` it.

Problem is I have a dropDown menu to only show data from specific planets. So I was wondering if it's possible to map of it again and only keep the ones that are equal to the current selected planet.
And if no planets are selected return all of them.

code i have so far

```
     class MainPage extends Component {

state = {
    data: [['name', 'min estimated diameter', 'max estimated diameter', { role: "planet" }]],


    dropDownOptions: [    
                        { value: 'all', label: 'All' },
                        { value: 'earth', label: 'Earth' },
                        { value: 'mars', label: 'Mars' },
                        { value: 'mercury', label: 'Mercury' },
                        { value: 'venus', label: 'Venus' },
                        { value: 'saturn', label: 'Saturn' },
                        { value: 'jupiter', label: 'Jupiter' },
                        { value: 'no orbited planet', label: 'No orbited planet'}
                    ],
    SelectedDropDownOption: { value: 'all', label: 'All' },

}

 componentDidMount() {

  this.getDataHandler()
 }


  getDataHandler= () => {
  axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?api_key=DEMO_KEY',)
.then((response) => {
    const restructuredData = response.data.near_earth_objects.map(
      ({ name, estimated_diameter, close_approach_data }) => {
        const close_approaches = close_approach_data && 
     close_approach_data.length
      ? close_approach_data.map(({ orbiting_body }) => orbiting_body)
      : ["no orbited planet"] 

        return [

          name,
          estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_min,
          estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_max,
          close_approaches[0]
        ]
      } 
    )

    const joined = this.state.data.concat(restructuredData)

    this.setState({ data: joined })
  })
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
})
}


DropDownChangeHandler= (SelectedDropDownOption) => {
console.log("hello")
this.setState({SelectedDropDownOption});
 }

render () {

    console.log(this.state.data)
    console.log(this.state.SelectedDropDownOption)
    console.log(this.state.SelectedDropDownOption.value)
   return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <DropDown options={this.state.dropDownOptions} onChange={this.getPlanetInformation}/>
        <Chart chartData={this.state.data} />
    </React.Fragment>
    );
}
}
```

export default MainPage;

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` method to achieve your goal. You loop over every sub array and you keep only those which includes the require planet name passed as function parameter.

```
const arrayList = [["21277 (1996 TO5)", 1.6016033798, 3.5812940302, "Mars"], ["162038 (1996 DH)", 1.2721987854, 2.844722965, "no orbited planet"], ["189058 (2000 UT16)", 1.332155667, 2.978790628, "Earth"],["276274 (2002 SS41)", 0.9650614696, 2.1579430484, "Earth"], ["322913 (2002 CM1)", 1.214940408, 2.7166893409, "Jupiter"]]

const getPlanetInformation = (planet) => {
  const information = arrayList.filter(item => item.includes(planet))
  console.log(information)
  return information.length ? information : arrayList
}
```

If there is no planet selected from your dropdown value or the selected doesn't exists inside your array, you can just return the initial value.

Comment: Where should i place the code if i need to get the selected planet from state ?

Comment: I edited my original post to include what i have so far.

Comment: Where is your render method ?

Comment: You missed your imports, from which library come from `DropDown` ?

Comment: react-select, with just a simple dropdown component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205830/discussion-between-hurobaki-and-ivar515).